# How to listen to dll function calls

Tags: c++, dll, system

is there any way to "listen" to when a function of a dll is called?

I would like to know what functions of a dll is called and the parameters etc....

is it possible?

thanks!

Comment: Please specify your OS. I guess you are looking for an ltrace for Windows.

Comment: do you have the source code of that DLL? if yes, what compiler are you using?

Comment: no.. I don't have the source code... all I know is that it was compiled with vc++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [WinApiOverride32](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/). This is a really powerful monitor, with support of COM and .NET and easily customizable (you can monitor DLL internal functions as well). Also, you can write a custom DLL to override some APIs called by the target.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "listen" to WinAPI (assuming) calls (for example user32.dll, gdi32.dll, etc.) made by 3rd party programs, you want to hook (detour) those calls. If this is the case, I suggest you to visit [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) project page.

Also, remember you need some sort of IPC method between the two processes. Boost's [message_queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue.html) has been proven to be quite handy.

Comment: thaks, but it's not for winapi... it's for a custom made dll

Answer (score 0):

There is one great debugger that might help you out: [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/).

It is quite tedious to use but with no source in the hands, it is something quite useful.

Comment: And it is free, I forgot to mention it.